# Problems with a display.jsx not working (useState ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my file called Display.jsx and I'm trying to build a calculator, this should be the display of it.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Display = ({ currentInput }) => {
  console.log(`Display Component - currentInput: ${currentInput}`);
  return (
    <div className="display" readOnly>
      <p>{currentInput}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

Display.propTypes = {
  currentInput: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Display;
```

I can see on console the numbers working but they're not displayed on screen I don't know why.

I placed some `console.log()` so I could see where the problem is, and I'm pretty sure it has something to do with `useState`. The thing is that this `currentInput` should be updated whenever I press a button but it's ignored I guess.

[I pressed some buttons but still there's nothing on my display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AseRO.png)

My repository:
https://github.com/IkPc/javascript-calculator